# Redux-logger with combineRedcuers (webpack2)

Tags: javascript, logging, redux

I can't seem to get my stateTransformer to work for Redux-logger.
I am using combineRedcuers from 'redux-immutable' and I want to log my actions as plain JS objects.

This is very clear how to do in the documentation, but I can't seem to get it to work. This is what I'm currently attempting.

My logger: (logger.js)

```
const stateTransformer = (state) => {
   const newState = {};
      for (let i of Object.keys(state)) {
      console.log(i)
      if (Immutable.Iterable.isIterable(state[i])) {
         console.log(newState)
         newState[i] = state[i].toJS();
       } else {
          newState[i] = state[i];
       }
    }
    return newState;
 }

 export const logger = createLogger({
    collapsed: true,
    stateTransformer
 })
```

Then I have my index.js where I apply my middlewares.

```
 const store = createStore(
     reducers,
     applyMiddleware(
        thunk,
        logger
     )
 )
```

Everything seems to be logging correctly, except the fact that my Immutable objects aren't logged as plain JS. Anyone have any suggestions? This are the version I'm using, if relevant.

```
"redux-immutable": "^4.0.0",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.1",
```

Edit: This is the current output for a action

```
size: 1
__altered: false
__hash:undefined
__ownerID:undefined
_root:ArrayMapNode
__proto__:Object
```

It's still logged as an immutable object.

Comment: Can you give the ouput of "aren't logged as plain JS"?

Comment: @ArchNoob See updated above. It's still being printed as an immutable object.

Comment: `if (Immutable.Iterable.isIterable(state[i])) {
         console.log(newState)
         newState[i] = state[i].toJS();
`  shouldn't this line be `newState[i] = state[i].toJS(); \n console.log(newState)`?